# Hibernate annotations for Serial id in Postgres 9.1

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql-9.1, hibernate-annotations

I have an error when I compile my Java code with this annotation:

```
@Id
@Column(name="\"idClass\"", unique=true, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idClass;
```

with  `<property name="show_sql">true</property>`
in debug it returns:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
```

The id column is serial. Any ideas?
I've tried to compile with `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)` but doesn't run. Thanks.

**[SOLVED]**

My solution is:

```
     @Id
     @SequenceGenerator(name="IDCLASS_GENERATOR", sequenceName="\"table_idClass_seq\"", allocationSize = 1)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IDCLASS_GENERATOR")
     @Column(name="\"idClass\"")
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What exactly you want to ask here?

Comment: Which annotation I have to use to mapping serial id in Postgres?

Comment: Why do you have those escaped quotes, "\"idClass\""? Try with 
@Id
@Column(name="\"idClass\"")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

Comment: *"\" \""* is used because Hibernate is case sensitive, anyway if I use your code it returns *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException Column called "<< idClass >>" is not in this 'ResultSet'.* @Petar

Comment: @django what's your column name in database?

Comment: @Petar it is *idClass*.

Answer (score 0):

See below code

```
@Column(name="idClass", unique=true, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "serial")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Integer idClass;
```

or you can use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name idClass was not found in this ResultSet*. This exception is fired when is called *session.saveOrUpdate(myObject);* where *myObject* contains all values for the corresponding table except for *idClass* because it is serial and not setted.

Comment: Try with @Id @Column(name="\"idClass\"")

Comment: Now org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: *ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():...* @JavaBeigner

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is case sensitivity, tu use case sensitive column name you must wrap it with backticks.

```
@Id 
@Column(name="`idClass`") 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Integer idClass;
```